# web.xml configuration based on Maven profile

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, web.xml

What maven plugin can be used to have the `appengine-web.xml` application generated based on the maven profile run, for example `-Pdev` or `-Pprod`

**Example:**

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>myapp-dev</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <static-files/>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <precompilation-enabled>false</precompilation-enabled>
</appengine-web-app>
```

For a `-Pdev`, and when the profile is `-Pprod`

The application name would be: `<application>myapp-prod</application>`

Comment: I think you should select one of the answers as correct. Both are acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Maven Replacer plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) and use it to replace a given String **-VERSION-** in my appengine-web.xml. This way I get multiple settings on Jenkins (using push to deploy) to deploy on different versions with the same code.

It's not really fancy but gets the job done.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <file>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml</file>
                    <token>-VERSION-</token>
                    <value>${app_version}</value>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use maven-war-plugin to change version and name of your application

On appengine-web.xml, write below lines

```
<application>${appengine.app}</application>
<version>${version.number.gae}</version>
```

And this is maven plugin you need

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</webappDirectory>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/resources/application.properties</filter>
            <filter>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml</filter>
        </filters>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/appengine-web.xml</include>
                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                    <include>open_graph/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>

        <!-- Exclude all timestamp specific static files. (see maven-resource-plugin in this pom.xml) -->
        <warSourceExcludes>css/**,flash/**,mobile/**,images/**,<!--js/**,-->sounds/**,channel.html</warSourceExcludes>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And maven profiles

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <appengine.app>my-gae-dev</appengine.app>
            <version.number.gae>1</version.number.gae>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <appengine.app>my-gae-prod</appengine.app>
            <version.number.gae>1</version.number.gae>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: This used to work in my case but now I updated all the tools: after a build "target\generated-sources\appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml" still contains ${appengine.app}