# AppEngine API client-authentification stopped working after update

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Java app engine backend with a web client and an Android client. The Android client uses the generated client library and the website the JavaScript client library for the endpoints.

We have 3 environments on app engine: Dev, Staging and Production.
I already pushed the update to dev and it is working on the app and the website.

Now I have updated the backend on the Staging environment and I get a lot of authentification problems. There is nothing changed in the authentification or the signing of the app so I don't understand what it can be.

#### Website client

The website uses G+ login and after calling a method of the custom app engine API it gives the following error:

`"Access Not Configured.  has not been used in project 986034197583 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting [url] then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."`

The discovery#restDescription is succesful and it shows the methods.

#### Android client

The Android app also uses G+ login and gives the following errors (in the log of the Google Cloud Console):

`com.google.api.server.spi.auth.GoogleJwtAuthenticator authenticate: ClientId is not allowed: 986034197583-51qasim2gmqql5vc652vk3u3lpapegb6.apps.googleusercontent.com`

The app is not signed with another keystore and the SHA-1 hash is the same (I checked it).

#### API Manager Credentials

The credentials in the API manager stayed the same and should not have to change. I checked them all and they look correct. This makes no sense to me unless Google has some stupid failure or something today.

#### APIs Explorer

When I test the API with the APIs Explorer it is working. (apis-explorer.appspot.com)

It looks like the API credentials are not linked to my API any more. I find it strange that you nowhere can enable or disable your own APIs (only the Google ones). The link in the error to activate the API does not work because it is a link as if it is a Google API.

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is creating a whole new project because I tried everything... But I don't want to experience the same thing on production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was something wrong with the backend configuration. I only replaces the appengine-web.xml with the staging configuration. But I did not change the clientID and the weblientId of the backend because they are in a file named Constants.java where I have to manually set if it is a DEV, STAGING or PRODUCTION backend (aarggh). This was still marked as DEV.

We really need a buildscript for this backend to prevent situations like this. Because I'm an Android developer I only know gradle. This project was developed by a Java developer who leaved the company and now I have to maintain this. It uses Maven so I don't know how I can make different build targets like in Android Studio where different Constants are used.

Maybe somebody here knows how I can make a simular solution like flavours in gradle with and generated BuildConfig.java Constants. That would be great.

**Edit**
I'm now creating maven profiles now in combination with the maven-war-plugin I can make different profiles for the different build types. This is usable for the different appengine-web.xml
See: [web.xml configuration based on Maven profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29295297/199252)
I'm now still trying too find something to include the Constants for ANDROID_CLIENT_ID and WEB_CLIENT_ID in the build script. I can't load them from a file because they have to be constants because they are used in attributes for the API's.
I generate the Contstants.java with http://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/. Only thing I can't get to work is that it does not generate it automaticcaly when swithing profile. I still have to manually start templating:filter-sources.